# how to highlight exact words only in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

in Visual Studio Code when I double-click on a word then all occurrences (strings and sub-strings) are highlighted on editor, how to highlight exact words only?

Example:

```
tNumber
tNumberTriviaModel
number
my number is
my Number is
```

if I double-click on `number` word, I expect exact words to be highlighted only, not: tNumber, tNumberTriviaModel, or Number.

Answer (score 2):

Just select the case match in search, and then double click also follows the constraint.
You can also select word length match right next to case match to make it more customized based on your requirement.

[image]

You can also turn on "Smart Case" search setting. That way, if search text has uppercase character, it will enable case sensitivity in search constraints.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make it permanent within the settings? because you would have to specify those values every time you modify the search box

Comment: If you modify the search box, what do you expect a permanent setting would do? Would it not let you modify search box?

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα I have edited my answer to help you a bit further, maybe thats what you want.